# How to determine if SQLAlchemy session needs comit

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How to determine if SQLAlchemy session needs commit? Here is a sample code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
    import os
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
    from sqlalchemy.orm import relation, validates

    DeclBase = declarative_base()
    class Parent(DeclBase):
        __tablename__ = 'parent'
        id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column('name', String)
        children = relation('Child', back_populates='parent')

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<Parent(id='%d', name='%s')>" % (self.id, self.name)
        def __init__ (self, id, name=''):
            self.id = id
            self.name = name

    class Child(DeclBase):
        __tablename__ = 'child'
        id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column('name', String)
        parent_id = Column('parent', Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
        parent = relation('Parent', back_populates='children')

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<Child(id='%d', name='%s')>" % (self.id, self.name)
        def __init__ (self, id, parent, name=''):
            self.id = id
            self.name = name
            self.parent_id = parent

    ## Main()

    dbengine = create_engine('postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
        'swms-dba', 'swms-dba', 'localhost', 5432, 'swmsdb'),                                                 
        client_encoding='utf8')
    dbsession = sessionmaker(bind=dbengine)()
    p1 = Parent(1,'Parent')
    dbsession.add(p1)
    c1 = Child(1,1,'Child#1')
    dbsession.add(c1)
    c2 = Child(2,1,'Child#2')
    dbsession.add(c2)

    print('Before:', dbsession.dirty, dbsession.new, dbsession.deleted)

    query = dbsession.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id==1)
    if query.count() == 1:
        parent=query.one()
        print(parent)
        for child in parent.children:
            print(child)

    print('After:', dbsession.dirty, dbsession.new, dbsession.deleted)
    dbsession.close()

    ## End
```

The output produced is:

```
    >test.py
    Before: IdentitySet([]) IdentitySet([<Parent(id='1', name='Parent')>,
             <Child(id='1', name='Child#1')>,
             <Child(id='2', name='Child#2')>]) IdentitySet([])
    <Parent(id='1', name='Parent')>
    <Child(id='1', name='Child#1')>
    <Child(id='2', name='Child#2')>
    After: IdentitySet([]) IdentitySet([]) IdentitySet([])
```

If I set autoflush to False in call to sessionmaker(), The IdentitySets do not become empty in the second print. However, query() doesn't yeild any instances :( Looks like with autoflush set to True, the query() triggers a flush which empties the IdentitySet

Comment: Regarding "Looks like with autoflush set to True, the query() triggers a flush which empties the IdentitySet": http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing.

Comment: Agreed. But my main question is about determining if there are any transaction in the session that needs commit/rollback. The IdentitySets do not definitively answer that question as it gets emptied by autoflush issued by any intermediate queries :(

Comment: May I ask you why do you need to know that? Usually one wraps their operations in a transactional context and that's that. The fact that the "new", "dirty", etc. sets are emptied by flush does not mean that you don't need to commit. Flush just sends the changes held by the Session to the database, but it does not commit. Commit on the other hand always flushes.

Comment: Actually, the above code is just an illustration of the problem. In my event driven software, changes including new table rows and deletion happens asynchronously. And use chooses to commit/rollback at intermediate intervals. However, when user chooses to quit application, I want to determine if there are changes to database add/update/del that needs to be committed/rolled-back and prompt user accordingly. So, I need auto-flush capability but also a way to determine if there are changes to DB since last commit/rollback.